# Improper integral convergence test $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^9+1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I've come this far in my computations:

$$0\le\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^9+1}}dx\le\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^9}}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{(x^9)^{1/3}}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^3}=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x}dx.$$

The last integral is divergent according to the $p-$test. However this does not show that the original integral has to be divergent too. The above result says that the original integral either diverges, but can also converge.

I somehow need to have the last integral less than or equal to the original one. Any trick here?

Comment: Can you find a $c$ such that $\sqrt[3]{x^9+1} \leqslant c\cdot x^3$ (for large enough $x$)?

Comment: as $x\rightarrow \infty$ the integrand behaves as $1/x$ and therefore the integral diverges

Comment: A lower bound can produced in a similar manner: $$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^9+1}}>\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^9+x^9}}$$which is essentially what [Kenny Lau's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2475869/272831) demonstrates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^9+1}}dx\ge\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{2\sqrt[3]{x^9}}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{2(x^9)^{1/3}}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{2x^3}=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{2x}dx=\infty$$

Comment: I almost get it. Shouldn't it be $$\sqrt[3]{x^9+x^9}=\sqrt[3]{2x^9}=2^{1/3}x^3?$$ How do you get a clean 2 there?

Comment: Ahh. you add $7x^9$ instead of only $x^9$ at the start right?

Comment: @Parseval it doesn't matter, since $2^{1/3} < 2$.